# Component props.dispatch doesnt work. React redux

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, redux, reactjs

I need help. In my colorcontrol I am trying to do a `this.props.dispatch(triggerFBEvent(fbID, method, params))` with no luck. 
What works though is if I were to just do just `triggerFBEvent(fbID, method, params)`. I am getting the error: 
`index.bundle.js:61968 Uncaught TypeError: this.props.dispatch is not a function`

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to send in new props with the line above, and then on

`componentWillMount() {
      this.props.dispatch(fetchFBEvent(this.props.fbID, "getColor"))
    }`

Call a custom service to update state with appropriate colors. But this.props.dispatch is not a function there either.

```
import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import {triggerFBEvent, triggerFBClearEvent, fetchFBEvent} from '../actions/functionblocksActions'
`
import { CustomPicker, HuePicker, SaturationPicker, SliderPicker, CustomPointer } from 'react-color';


@connect((store) => {
  return {
    fb: store.functionblocks.functionblock
  }
})

export default class Functionblock extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.state = {

      };
    this._getType = this._getType.bind(this)

  }
      _getType (wanted) {
        const { fbID, fbName, func } = this.props;
        let type;
        let types = {
          'com.xxxx.xx.service.dal.functions.Alarm': function () {
            type = <Alarm fbID={fbID} fbName={fbName}/>;
          },
          'com.xxxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.BooleanControl': function () {
            type = <BooleanControl fbID={fbID} fbName={fbName}/>;
          },
          'com.xxx.xxxx.service.dal.functions.BooleanSensor': function () {
            type = <BooleanSensor fbID={fbID} fbName={fbName} />;
          },
          'com.xxxx.xxx.service.dal.functions.ColorControl': function () {
            type = <ColorControl func={func} fbID={fbID} fbName={fbName} />;
          }

          'default': function () {
            type = <WakeUp fbID={fbID} fbName={fbName} />;
          }
        };

        // invoke it
        (types[wanted] || types['default'])();

        // return a String with chosen type
        return type;
      }

  render() {
    const { fbID, fbName, func } = this.props;
    const type = this._getType(func.serviceProperties["clazz"]);


      return( 
        <div>
        {type}
        </div>
      )
  }
}


// Classes for the different functions.
class ColorControl extends React.Component {
    componentWillMount() {
      this.props.dispatch(fetchFBEvent(this.props.fbID, "getColor"))
    }
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          color: {
            h: 150.3197479248047,
            s: 0.5,
            l: 0.5
          }
        }
        this.onChangeComplete = this.onChangeComplete.bind(this);
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      alert("YEP")
    // let home = this._getHome(nextProps.areas, nextProps.statics);
    // if(home!=null){
    //   this.setState({
    //     inputHome: home.name,
    //   })
    // }
    }
    onChangeComplete(color, event) {

        let hsl = color.hsl;

        let hue = color.hsl.h / 360;
        let saturation = color.hsl.s;
        let lightness = color.hsl.l;

        this.setState({ color: hsl })

        // Update props
        let fbID = this.props.fbID;
        let method = "setColor";
        let params = {"hue": hue, "sat": saturation, "light": lightness};
        this.props.dispatch(triggerFBEvent(fbID, method, params))

      }
    _defineFunction(){

    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
          <SliderPicker {...this.props}
          pointer={ CustomPointer }
          color={this.state.color}
          onChangeComplete={ this.onChangeComplete }
          direction={ 'horizontal' || 'vertical' }/>

        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me understand whats going wrong?

Comment: Is ColorControl connected to redux?

Comment: It doesn't seem like you are using `connect` for `ColorControl`.  If you are using the decorator syntax, then you need to add `@connect` just above the `ColorControl` component definition as well.  Unless, of course, it is a child of a connected component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect `ColorControl` to Redux, otherwise it doesn't get a dispatch prop.

```
@connect()
class ColorControl extends React.Component {
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the codebase to use your actions without problems.

```
import * as actions from './YourActionsPath'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

@connect(  
  state => ({
    yourDerivedState : state.somePath
  }),
  dispatch => ({
    actions : bindActionCreators( actions, dispatch )
  })
)

export default class YourClass extends Component {
  someMethod(){
    this.props.actions.yourAction() // call it with no problems
  }
  render(){
    return (
      // your html
    )
  }
}
```

I hope you get the idea. If you use this patterns, you won't have problems.

As you can use your derived state as this.props.derivedState, which you define in the connect, you can also use your actions you defined on the connect.

Besides you can use this.props.dispatch if you connected your component. In case you need it as in your case, but this makes the code less clear and leads to maintainance problems.

Answer (score -1):

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
let store = createStore(//define reducer,preload state and enhancer)

//call action 
store.dispatch(triggerFBEvent(fbID, method, params))
```